# How to know if a transaction gets dropped and txhash becomes irrelevant before its mined

Tags: web3js, pending-transactions, hash

I am using a web3 sendTransaction function to send coins, and then storing the transactionHash in my databse

```
await web3SendInstance.eth.sendTransaction({to:receiveAddress, from:web3.eth.defaultAccount, value:amount, chainId:chainid, gas:21000, gasPrice:currentGasPrice, txHash:txHash,})
            .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
          
               saveTxHash(hash);

            })
```

The problem is that sometimes these transactions get dropped and never mined, and so the hash that is returned is irrelevant.

How do I check that the txhash doesn't get dropped, and why is it sometimes dropped?

Comment: What was the error? be clear please there too many reasons a transaction (sendTransaction) has an error. Also what is txHash? Have you tried to use only: from, to, and value parameters.

Comment: I didn't say it threw an error, I said that the transaction hash becomes irrelevant. There are no errors, I get returned a hash from the .on() function but that hash sometimes isn't a hash that links to any transaction on etherscan

Answer (score -1):

I didn't see any issue here, I removed the txHash:txHash,. Interesting was your transaction on testnet or mainnet?

```
truffle(develop)> await web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:'0x765659e499cb2cd7ba3c8eb7a114636032be208b', from:'0xde9155dcb95c66f57d6678845931d0db2ffeeb4a', value:'1000', chainId:'1337', gas:'21000', gasPrice:'20000000000'}).on('transactionHash', function(hash){console.log('hash', hash)})
hash 0x561c11132a68dd67c7bcfae13e8cfa9981d7264583175e215c962ffbcdd2b422
{
  transactionHash: '0x561c11132a68dd67c7bcfae13e8cfa9981d7264583175e215c962ffbcdd2b422',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  blockHash: '0x06cae82646744772b661b8c5aa63b53b6e6e04ec73fcd919ba3f4ebc836a4a0b',
  blockNumber: 3,
  from: '0xde9155dcb95c66f57d6678845931d0db2ffeeb4a',
  to: '0x765659e499cb2cd7ba3c8eb7a114636032be208b',
  gasUsed: 21000,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 21000,
  contractAddress: null,
  logs: [],
  status: true,
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
}
truffle(develop)> debug 0x561c11132a68dd67c7bcfae13e8cfa9981d7264583175e215c962ffbcdd2b422
Starting Truffle Debugger...

Addresses affected:
 0x765659e499CB2CD7Ba3c8EB7a114636032bE208B(UNKNOWN)

Warning: The source code for one or more contracts could not be found.
Warning: this transaction has no trace steps. This may happen if you are attempting to debug a transaction sent to an externally-owned account, or if the node you are connecting to failed to produce a trace for some reason. Please check your configuration and try again.

Commands:
(enter) last command entered (step next)
(o) step over, (i) step into, (u) step out, (n) step next
(c) continue until breakpoint
(;) step instruction (include number to step multiple)
(g) turn on generated sources, (G) turn off generated sources except via `;`
(p) print instruction & state (`p [mem|cal|sto]*`; see docs for more)
(l) print additional source context, (s) print stacktrace, (h) print this help
(q) quit, (r) reset, (t) load new transaction, (T) unload transaction
(b) add breakpoint (`b [[<source-file>:]<line-number>]`; see docs for more)
(B) remove breakpoint (similar to adding, or `B all` to remove all)
(+) add watch expression (`+:<expr>`), (-) remove watch expression (-:<expr>)
(?) list existing watch expressions and breakpoints
(v) print variables and values, (:) evaluate expression - see `v`




debug(develop:0x561c1113...)> i

Transaction completed successfully.
debug(develop:0x561c1113...)>
```