# web3SendInstance.eth.sendTransaction returning txhash but transactions get lost

Tags: web3js, pending-transactions, sendtransaction

I am using web3.eth.sendTransaction to try and send Ether from one address to another

```
    let result = await web3SendInstance.eth.sendTransaction({to:receiveAddress, from:web3.eth.defaultAccount, value:amount, chainId:chainid, gas:21000, gasPrice:currentGasPrice,})
        .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
            let info = {transactionHash : hash};
            addBridgetxhash(info, txHash);
        })
        .on('error', function(error)
        {
            console.log('THERE WAS AN ERROR!!!!!!!!!!');
            console.log(error);
        })            
        .then(events => addtxhash(events, txHash))
        .catch((err) => LogError(err, '=== sendNativeToken() ==='));
```

The gasPrice in this example 78585307262

The problem is that I get a txhash back from the .then() callback, but the txhash is not found on Etherscan. There is no pending transaction on Etherscan either. The transaction never resolves.

What is going on here? How can I debug this?

Some extra information, this is the txhash that I get back from my web3 instance: `0x067da419ca826e179325c51c29072bea766f080f9fdedb066af987ae8742d1ab`

Comment: Yo you already posted the same question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/110351/how-to-know-if-a-transaction-gets-dropped-and-txhash-becomes-irrelevant-before-i/110388#110388. Check your endpoint or post all your file

Comment: not really the same question. I'm using Infura as an endpoint

Comment: please add the endpoint and remove your project id.

Comment: if you want to send a transaction you could use something like, const signtx = web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
    from: from,
    to: to,
    value: web3.utils.toWei('2', 'ether'),
    gas: 2000000
}, privateKey ) then use sendSignedTransaction,  const createTx = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signtx.rawTransaction)

console.log(`transaction sent ${createTx.transactionHash}`)

Comment: you use sendTransaction() method if you unlocked the account (the from address account) otherwise you use signTransaction then sendSignedTransaction. You can read more about them.